# Python: (sampling with replacement): efficient algorithm to extract the set of DISSIMILAR N-tuples from a set

Tags: python, algorithm, big-o

I have a set of items, from which I want to select DISSIMILAR tuples (more on the definition of dissimilar touples later). The set could contain potentially several thousand items, although typically, it would contain only a few hundreds.

I am trying to write a generic algorithm that will allow me to select N items to form an N-tuple, from the original set. The new set of selected N-tuples should be **DISSIMILAR**.

A N-tuple **A** is said to be DISSIMILAR to another N-tuple **B** if and only if:

- Every pair (2-tuple) that occurs in A DOES NOT appear in B

Note: For this algorithm, A 2-tuple (pair) is considered SIMILAR/IDENTICAL if it contains the same elements, i.e. (x,y) is considered the same as (y,x).

This is a (possible variation on the) classic [Urn Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urn_problem). A trivial (pseudocode) implementation of this algorithm would be something along the lines of

```
def fetch_unique_tuples(original_set, tuple_size):
    while True:
        # randomly select [tuple_size] items from the set to create first set
        # create a key or hash from the N elements and store in a set
        # store selected N-tuple in a container
        if end_condition_met:
            break
```

I don't think this is the most efficient way of doing this - and though I am no algorithm theorist, I suspect that the time for this algorithm to run is NOT ***O(n)*** - in fact, its probably more likely to be ***O(n!)***. I am wondering if there is a more efficient way of implementing such an algo, and preferably, reducing the time to ***O(n)***.

Actually, as Mark Byers pointed out there is a second variable `m`, which is the size of the number of elements being selected. This (i.e. `m`) will typically be between 2 and 5.

Regarding examples, here would be a typical (albeit shortened) example:

```
original_list = ['CAGG', 'CTTC', 'ACCT', 'TGCA', 'CCTG', 'CAAA', 'TGCC', 'ACTT', 'TAAT', 'CTTG', 'CGGC', 'GGCC', 'TCCT', 'ATCC', 'ACAG', 'TGAA', 'TTTG', 'ACAA', 'TGTC', 'TGGA', 'CTGC', 'GCTC', 'AGGA', 'TGCT', 'GCGC', 'GCGG', 'AAAG', 'GCTG', 'GCCG', 'ACCA', 'CTCC', 'CACG', 'CATA', 'GGGA', 'CGAG', 'CCCC', 'GGTG', 'AAGT', 'CCAC', 'AACA', 'AATA', 'CGAC', 'GGAA', 'TACC', 'AGTT', 'GTGG', 'CGCA', 'GGGG', 'GAGA', 'AGCC', 'ACCG', 'CCAT', 'AGAC', 'GGGT', 'CAGC', 'GATG', 'TTCG']


# Select 3-tuples from the original list should produce a list (or set) similar to:

    [('CAGG', 'CTTC', 'ACCT')
     ('CAGG', 'TGCA', 'CCTG')
     ('CAGG', 'CAAA', 'TGCC')
     ('CAGG', 'ACTT', 'ACCT')
     ('CAGG', 'CTTG', 'CGGC')
     ....
     ('CTTC', 'TGCA', 'CAAA')
    ]
```

**[[Edit]]**

Actually, in constructing the example output, I have realized that the earlier definition I gave for UNIQUENESS was incorrect. I have updated my definition and have introduced a new metric of DISSIMILARITY instead, as a result of this finding.

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: You have defined one variable `n` but here are two variables here: the number of elements in the set, and the number of unique tuples you wish to find. The algorithm's performance may depend on both of these variables.

Comment: @MarkByers: Thanks for pointing that out. There is indeed another dimension `m` - the number of variables. `m` is typically in the range of between two and five - so perhaps, not too much a factor considering the potential size of `n`.

Comment: Is it a requirement that the result be a random selection?

Comment: @VaughnCato: No, the requirement is that the result consists of DISSIMILAR N-tuples (assuming we selecting N elements at a time). I have provided the definition for DISSIMILARITY (a boolean metric) above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried another approach--combinations of combinations.  It seems to work pretty swiftly:

```
def fetch_unique_tuples(original_set, tuple_size):
    from itertools import combinations

    good = []
    used = []
    for i in combinations(original_set,tuple_size):
        lst = list([tuple(sorted(j)) for j in combinations(i,2)])
        if not any(l in used for l in lst):
            used.extend(lst)
            good.append(tuple(sorted(i)))
    return sorted(good)

elements = ['CAGG', 'CTTC', 'ACCT', 'TGCA', 'CCTG', 'CAAA', 'TGCC', 'ACTT', 'TAAT', 'CTTG', 'CGGC', 'GGCC', 'TCCT', 'ATCC', 'ACAG', 'TGAA', 'TTTG', 'ACAA', 'TGTC', 'TGGA', 'CTGC', 'GCTC', 'AGGA', 'TGCT', 'GCGC', 'GCGG', 'AAAG', 'GCTG', 'GCCG', 'ACCA', 'CTCC', 'CACG', 'CATA', 'GGGA', 'CGAG', 'CCCC', 'GGTG', 'AAGT', 'CCAC', 'AACA', 'AATA', 'CGAC', 'GGAA', 'TACC', 'AGTT', 'GTGG', 'CGCA', 'GGGG', 'GAGA', 'AGCC', 'ACCG', 'CCAT', 'AGAC', 'GGGT', 'CAGC', 'GATG', 'TTCG']
uniques = fetch_unique_tuples(elements, 3)
print len(uniques)
```

Easily converted into a generator if you're willing to lose the capability of len().

*edit*: added additional sorted() to make all tuples and ultimate list alpha.

Comment: +1 for the code snippet. I'm amazed at the difference in speed. Trying to understand where the speed improvement is coming from (not very familiar with itertools)

Comment: Read my latest comment on luke's solution; its probably less the tools than sheer count of iterations.

Answer (score 1):

This is a trivial implementation of the algorithm. I'm not a theorist either but I love algorithms. I think this simple implementation is O(n^m) where m is the dimensions + something for the combinations, which should be less than O(n!).

```
def combine(elements,n=3):
    from itertools import combinations,product,ifilter

    hashes=[]
    combs=[]
    for p in combinations(elements,n):
        if len(set(p)) == 3 and not any(i in hashes for i in [sorted(i) for i in combinations(p,2)]):
            combs.append(p)
            hashes.extend([sorted(i) for i in combinations(p,2)])
    return combs

elements = ['CAGG', 'CTTC', 'ACCT', 'TGCA', 'CCTG', 'CAAA', 'TGCC', 'ACTT', 'TAAT', 'CTTG', 'CGGC', 'GGCC', 'TCCT', 'ATCC', 'ACAG', 'TGAA', 'TTTG', 'ACAA', 'TGTC', 'TGGA', 'CTGC', 'GCTC', 'AGGA', 'TGCT', 'GCGC', 'GCGG', 'AAAG', 'GCTG', 'GCCG', 'ACCA', 'CTCC', 'CACG', 'CATA', 'GGGA', 'CGAG', 'CCCC', 'GGTG', 'AAGT', 'CCAC', 'AACA', 'AATA', 'CGAC', 'GGAA', 'TACC', 'AGTT', 'GTGG', 'CGCA', 'GGGG', 'GAGA', 'AGCC', 'ACCG', 'CCAT', 'AGAC', 'GGGT', 'CAGC', 'GATG', 'TTCG']
print combine(elements)
```

Comment: Thanks for giving it a go. However, the solution you propose is not quite right. If you recall, the definition of DISSIMILAR was that NO 2-tuple (pair) should be identical between two selected N-tuples  [remember (x,y) <=> (y,x)]. The code above selects tuples like [('CAGG', 'CTTC', 'ACCT'), ('CAGG', 'CTTC', 'TGCA'), ... ]. These are not DISSIMILAR because the pair ('CAGG', 'CTTC') is common to more than one of the selected 3-tuples.

Comment: oh ok, I didn't get it. I'll think about it and come back with a new solution.

Comment: +1 for the effort. Yes, it is a bit slow - but at least, it seems to be working. I'll worry about 'optimizing' later. Need to run  a few checks to make sure its working as expected.

Comment: run it on pypy to make it go a bit faster.

Comment: @hexparrot yes i know. your code should be faster since you bruteforce on a c++ method

Comment: I'm not sure bruteforcing is the most appropriate description or that a "c++ method" explains the variance.  Your approach does nC2 on a product, whereas I just do nC2 on an nC3.  So your ifilter does 185193 iterations, where my combinations does 29260 iterations.

Comment: Comparing my code to slightly-changed code of yours shows that your approach (when greatly reducing iterations) runs more comparably to mine: http://ideone.com/SWtHG

Comment: the difference was in the "in" for the any which was placed element by element instead of "list-wise". Now it goes pretty much as fast as yours for n=3.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean that the set of M N-tuples must be pairwise dissimilar, it seems like using a graph to keep track of 'forbidden' pairs is the way to go.

```
import random
def select_tuples(original, N, M):
  used = {}
  first = random.sample(original, N)
  updateUsed(used, first)
  answer = [first]
  for i in xrange(M):
    notFound = True
    while notFound:
      remaining = set(original)
      thisTuple = []
      for j in xrange(N):
        if not remaining:
          break
        candidate = random.choice(remaining)
        remaining.remove(candidate)
        for adjacent in used[candidate]:
          remaining.remove(adjacent)
      else:
        notFound = False
    answer.append(thisTuple)
    updateUsed(used, thisTuple)
  return answer

def updateUsed(used, selected):
  for x in selected:
    if x not in used:
      used[x] = []
    for y in selected:
      if y != x:
        used[x].append(y)
```

This is something like `O(MN^2)`  I think. I doubt you'll be able to do much better than that as for each of the `M` tuples you're introducing `N*(N-1)/2` forbidden pairs which you can't use any more.